# Mapping and preimage

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Just to clarify, ∪c∈c" c , the c∈c" is below the union ∪. P(Y) is the power set of Y.

Let f : X -> Y be a map.

(a) Show that for any subset C ⊆ Y , one has

$f^{-1}$ (Y\C) = X\ $f^{-1}$(C)

(b) Show that for any collection c" ⊆ P(Y) of subsets in Y, one has

$f^{-1}$ (∪c∈c" c) = ∪c∈c" $f^{-1}$ (c)

(c) Show that for any collection c" ⊆ P(Y) of subsets in Y, one has

$f^{-1}$ (∩c∈c" c) = ∩c∈c" $f^{-1}$ (c)

My Solutions for (a) : x ∈ $f^{-1}$ (Y\C) if and only if f(x) ∈ Y and not f(x) ∈ C if and only if x ∈ $f^{-1}$ (Y) and not x ∈ $f^{-1}$ (C) if and only if x ∈ X\ $f^{-1}$(C) Can i prove LHS to RHS this way?

My Solutions for (b) : x ∈ $f^{-1}$ (∪c∈c" c) if and only if f(x) ∈ (∪c∈c" c) if and only if 
f(x) ∈ c for some c∈c" if and only if x ∈ $f^{-1}$ (c) for some c∈c" if and only if x ∈ ∪c∈c" $f^{-1}$(c).  Can i prove LHS to RHS this way?

My Solutions for (c) : its pretty similar, just replace union with intersection and replace for some with for every.

x ∈ $f^{-1}$ (∩c∈c" c) if and only if f(x) ∈ (∩c∈c" c) if and only if 
f(x) ∈ c for every c∈c" if and only if x ∈ $f^{-1}$ (c) for every c∈c" if and only if x ∈ ∩c∈c" $f^{-1}$(c). Can i prove LHS to RHS this way?

Comment: "Sorry for the bad representation of the mathematical terms!" It's not just bad; it's incomprehensible. What could X\f-1(C) possibly mean? There is some help on this site for formatting mathematics, maybe you can find it and read it and edit accordingly. Failing that, you could put in a few sentences like, "When I write f-1, what I mean is ...."

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback! I checked the math jax beginner tutorial. How do you key in inverse function?

Comment: That's better. $\cup$ is \cup. $\in$ is \in. $\cup_{c\in c''}$ is \cup_{c\in c''}. $\to$ is \to. $\cap$ is \cap. $\subseteq$ is \subseteq.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea, but you're overusing if and only if and making it a bit messy.
For example, to show $ f^{−1} (Y \backslash C) \supset X \backslash f^{-1}(C) $ in question (a), we are only required to notice that if $ x \in X \backslash f^{-1}(C) $ then $ f(x) \notin C$, or $ f(x) \in Y \backslash C $ hence $ x \in f^{-1} ( Y \backslash C ) $ as required.